# How to update a class variable in TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, class, websocket

I am trying to create a class that wraps a WebSocket and acts as an ingestor.

I have my ingestion working and I can pass a function to the class instance through a public function that will process incoming messages.

However I want to make a specific call to pull info from the WS and use that data to update a member of the class. I keep running into static error and things of the sort and am not sure how to go about it.

Originally I had just set my variable that I want to update outside of the class, but this means it would not be different for each instance. How can I store this variable in the class - per instance, while allowing me to make changes to it?

```
export class WebSocketWrapper {
    private _webSocket: WebSocketType;
    private _myVariableToUpdate: number;

    constructor(webSocket: WebSocketType) {
        this._webSocket = webSocket;
        setInterval(updateVariable, 5000);
    }

    // This gives problems
    private updateVariable() {
        this._myVariableToUpdate = this._webSocket.getMyVariable();
    }

    // This works
    public onXXX(handler: Function): void {
        this._webSocket.on("XXX", (value) => {
            this._webSocket.doSomething(value).then((v) => {
                handler(myValue);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: _"This gives problems"_ What problems? Describe what happens that is undesired. Do you get a specific error message? If so, add the exact error message to your question. Does your code do something unexpected? If so, describe the erroneous behavior.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, there may be a couple of issues.

First, you are likely triggering the [strictPropertyInitialization](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictPropertyInitialization) error. This is because the property `_myVariableToUpdate` is not initialized in the constructor directly. To get around this, you need to let typescript know that you are initializing it by other means by using the [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-):

```
private _myVariableToUpdate: number;
```

should become

```
private _myVariableToUpdate!: number;
```

Secondly, in the constructor, you are referring to an instance method without using the `this` keyword.

```
setInterval(updateVariable, 5000);
```

should become

```
setInterval(this.updateVariable, 5000);
```

So, with those changes in place, your class becomes the following:

```
export class WebSocketWrapper {
    private _webSocket: WebSocketType;
    private _myVariableToUpdate!: number;

    constructor(webSocket: WebSocketType) {
        this._webSocket = webSocket;
        setInterval(this.updateVariable, 5000);
    }

    private updateVariable() {
        this._myVariableToUpdate = this._webSocket.getMyVariable();
    }

    public onXXX(handler: Function): void {
        this._webSocket.on("XXX", (value) => {
            this._webSocket.doSomething(value).then((v) => {
                handler(myValue);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

For greater type-safety, I would actually either declare `_myVariableToUpdate` as

```
private _myVariableToUpdate?: number;
```

Or, make another call to `this.updateVariable` in the constructor that fires immediately

```
this.updateVariable();
setInterval(this.updateVariable, 5000);
```